# When to allow deep object navigation and when to avoid it?

Tags: oop

I was wondering if there was any best practices or rules that can help to determine whether deep navigation should be allowed from an object root or not. So far, I've almost always preferred to hide all implementation details, but it might be overkill.

By deep navigation, I mean something like `httpResponse.status().text()` rather than `httpResponse.statusText()` considering that `HttpResponse` encapsulates a `HttpStatus` object.

The latter completely hide implementation details, but also requires more code. I understand the example is perhaps oversimplictic and `HttpResponse` has no invariants to enforce other than preventing a `null` status, but it's enough to expose the problem.

Please note that we can consider `HttpStatus` as immutable for the example.

It might not be the best example, but we can also use any example where composition is used over inheritance.

Comment: My first question would simply be, why would would you want to do that?

Comment: @mituw16, do what? The whole http thing is just an example of composition.

Comment: I understand that, I don't understand why would in an example want to allow or disallow object navigation. It seems to me the best way to code any objects would be code them in a manner that is logical and efficient. Think of it this way, what benefit would someone gain by having to type `httpResponse.StatusText()` vs. `httpResponse.status().text()`? In that scenario, personally, I would think that it would be overkill as you would have to write more code  to hide the `.text()` method. But that's just my opinion

Comment: @mituw16 Yes, the example is perhaps too trivial as it is. The only advantage I would see is that the public `HttpStatus` API could change independently of the `HttpResponse`'s API. However, I guess we would already violating some principles by allowing the public interface of a class to change in the first place. My question makes more sense if we think about when composition is used over inheritance or when a class is composed of many members such as a `Car` having a `Motor` and a `GPS`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Clean Code](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/agile-development/9780136083238/objects-and-data-structures/ch06), we can read that:

> Objects hide their data behind abstractions and expose functions that
>   operate on that data. Data structure expose their data and have no
>   meaningful functions.

I think this answers my question really well. In the example above we can safely assume that `httpResponse` is a data structure so there is no reason to hide it's structural details. However, if it was an object with behaviours, then following the [Tell Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle would usually be more appropriate.